# Enable form based login in Jboss EAP 6.3

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

Following the [official tutorial](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.3/html/Security_Guide/Enable_Form-based_Authentication.html) form-based auth is achieved by simply adding this to web.xml:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/loginform.html</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/loginerror.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

I did that, but web.xml gets ignored when deploying.

```
[WARNING] Warning: selected war files include a WEB-INF/web.xml which will be ig
nored
(webxml attribute is missing from war task, or ignoreWebxml attribute is specifi
ed as 'true')
```

The loginForm.jsp is this:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>loginForm.jsp</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Please login to add employees</h2>
    <form action="j_security_check" method=post>
        <p><strong>Username: </strong>
            <input type="text" name="j_username" size="25">
        <p><p><strong>Password: </strong>
        <input type="password" size="15" name="j_password">
        <p><p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Full web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>form_auth</display-name>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/loginform.html</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/loginerror.html</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

How do I achieve form-based auth?

Comment: maybe you should add some more information, what exactly did you place in your web.xml, where is the security constraint and how did you write the login-form. Also, what do you mean by "web.xml gets ignored"

Comment: And the web.xml is loaded properly if you remove the login configuration?

Comment: @thst no, it's always ignored as far as I can see. Maybe it's togglable somewhere, but I don't know.

Comment: Then the web.xml is possibly broken. Can you post it completely?

Comment: @thst added it, also expanded on the error during deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Looks too short to me. There is no security constraint to trigger the form based login, so it is never used.

Otherwise, there is nothing in there, no servlets, no default page. I suppose the web.xml parser optimizes the login config away, as it will never be triggered, and then you are left with an empty descriptor - which is then ignored.

Try to add a security constraint on the "/" path or some sub-path, then try to access it using the browser. That should trigger your form login config.

Update: You find the security constraints description and how to in the JBoss tutorial you mentioned, just one chapter before "form based login". https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.3/html/Security_Guide/Web_Content_Security_Constraints.html

Comment: How do I add a security constraint? To what file?